# Database.convertLead - FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Validation error on Lead: Select an Individual record type.: []

Tags: apex, validation-rule, lead-conversion

I am trying to deploy a class with a test that automatically converts leads.  This Apex method will be invoked via Process Builder.  It works fine in the Sandbox environment, and the test worked fine before the new year, but now it is failing when promoting as well as re-running in the Sandbox.

Looking through the debug logs, the exception occurs within the call to database.convertLead

10:50:32.455 (9455361693)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[16]|System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Validation error on Lead: Select an Individual record type.: []

I am using Financial Services Cloud, and the default record type "Individual" is there with no specific mappings, following https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_services_cloud_object_reference.meta/financial_services_cloud_object_reference/fsc_api_mdt_individual_record_type_mapper.htm

And additional error upward on the log is:
10:50:32.277 (9372172718)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[EXTERNAL]|this|"common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException"|0x2fa3e1f2
10:50:32.277 (9372214051)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[EXTERNAL]|message|"Record Type does not (6 more) ..."

I would love to know what "6 more" refers to.

```apex
    @isTest(SeeAllData=true)
          public class TestAutoConvertLeads{
          static testMethod void createnewlead() {
          User userToCreate = [Select id from user where profile.name='System Administrator' AND isActive = true limit 1];
          Recordtype recordtypeid = [Select id from recordtype where developername = 'Referral' Limit 1];
          
          Test.startTest();    
          Lead leadToCreate =new Lead();
          List<id> Ids= New List<Id>();
          leadToCreate.ownerid= userToCreate.id;
          leadToCreate.LastName ='TestLead';
          leadToCreate.Company='TestLead';
          leadToCreate.LeadSource='Social Channels';
          leadToCreate.Rating='';
          leadToCreate.Status='';
          leadToCreate.recordtypeid= recordtypeid.id;
          insert leadToCreate; 
          
          Ids.add(leadToCreate.id);
          AutoConvertLeads.LeadAssign(Ids);
          
          Account[] newAccount = [Select id from Account WHERE LastName = 'TestLead'];
          System.assert(!newAccount.isEmpty());
    
          Test.stopTest();
       }
    }

    Public class AutoConvertLeads 
    {     @InvocableMethod   
        public static void LeadAssign(List<Id> LeadIds)  
        {         
            LeadStatus CLeadStatus= [SELECT Id, ApiName FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true and ApiName = 'Closed' Limit 1];    
            List<Database.LeadConvert> MassLeadconvert = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();    
            for(id currentlead: LeadIds){                
                Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new Database.LeadConvert();    
                Leadconvert.setLeadId(currentlead);                               
                Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus(CLeadStatus.ApiName);             
                Leadconvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(FALSE);
                MassLeadconvert.add(Leadconvert);    
            }                  
            if (!MassLeadconvert.isEmpty())
            {            
                List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(MassLeadconvert);       // fails here
            }    
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked if the user profile has assigned this record type? Individual on this case.

Comment: Good call, but yes, the user profile does indeed have the record type.  Adding the example Lead created in the test.

Comment: I'm confused, the test that creates the Lead assign the record type 'Referral'. Is that what you intended? I thought you wanted to use Individual (maybe that is part of FSC config). Btw: avoid seeAllData.

Comment: "Individual" is an Account record type, not Lead.

Comment: I understand the issues with seeAllData, but I need the LeadStatus table populated - it worked fine as of December - I'm trying to get a support case with Salesforce to make sure something didn't change inside the Database.convertLead method.

Comment: I get you, no worries: could it be because of these changes: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_nc.htm&type=5&release=230

Comment: The "6 more" refer to the " exist" string. As in "record type does not exist".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a support call with Salesforce Tier 2, they were able to determine that there was an added validation that the lead required a product defined and that the test would work if I also omitted the Company Name.  It may have to do with the changes that Jeferson mentioned.